# Parquet Output File Not Compressed

Tags: hive

I am executing below command in hive console.

```
create table departments_parquet stored as parquet tblproperties("parquet.compression"="GZIP") as select * from departments;
```

I see the output file created in parquet format as below.

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 cloudera supergroup        463 2017-06-17 14:55 /user/hive/warehouse/departments_parquet/000000_0
```

Hive relevant properties are set as :

```
mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
hive.exec.compress.output=true;
```

I expected the output file name as 000000_0.gz 
Please help to get the final output as compressed gzip file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columnar storage usage various compression techniques simultaneously and page compression is just one of them, therefor, although containing gzipped data parts, the files are not gzipped files.